# read first five lines of a files from s3 using python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I tried to read s3 files using boto3

the code used is below

```
    content = s3.Object('bucket','objectkey').get()['Body'].read()
    StringVariable=content.decode('UTF-8','ignore')
    x = StringVariable.split('\n')
    str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in x)
    print(str1)
```

it gets all the lines as bytes so i  used decode and stored as string.

the output needed is only the first 5 lines to be read and stored as string.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
 str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in x)
 print(str1)
```

with this:

```
  for i in range(5):
        print(x[i])
```

It will only print the first five lines as you wanted it.

Comment: Are you sure that you atleast 5 lines in the list?

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.